# UITabBar with count indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

Is it possible to show a count indicator on top of a tab bar item? How?

The application has several tabs, and in some of them there might be updated information. I'm looking for a way to make the user notice when there is something new in one of the tabs...

I'm thinking of a round count indicator as is shown on top of the application icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up UITabBarItem property badgeValue. Use UITabBar to get the item